# How to add text to an image and users can also saved the image with the added text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, interactive

Again I've been finding the solution for this, if you're not understand my question, here's some demonstration.

I set my name as "Peter"

and I have a congratulation poster which has a space for put a name in it

when the user reach this page, the poster will generate the name and the poster and they can save
both of the picture with the text in it.
** I have no demonstration code for this because I really have no idea how to do it. and I wish there's a possible way to do it as well...

Comment: oh also the poster is a picture file format (jpg or png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML Canvas for this.
just draw the image when it loads on canvas and then draw the texts on it.
And export the canvas using `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")`. this will create a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) for the stuff drawn on canvas. After getting the URL just put that as `href` in an HTML `<a>` tag and set the [`download`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute to it.

on clicking the link it will start downloading

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let img = new Image("Image_URL_here");
img.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.font = '50px serif';
  ctx.fillText('Hello world', 50, 90);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the right response, Kumar. But, according with documentation,

> "If you try to call drawImage() before the image has finished loading,
> it won't do anything (or, in older browsers, may even throw an
> exception). So you need to be sure to use the load event so you don't
> try this before the image has loaded"
> [WEB Api - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)

This change make your example works here. Full code (sorry, I mixed the sample with MDN graph code 8D):

stack.html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="stack1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

stack1.js:

```
function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.font = '50px serif';
    ctx.fillText('Hello world', 50, 90);
  });
  img.src = "backdrop.png";
}
```

Catch the image "backdrop.png" from MDN to your local directory to make it works.