# Is there a way to create a new image from some text and another image, in js?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body id="slshow_body" style="text-align: center;" >
<h2>Add new sliding image</h2>
<img name="simage1" id="simage1" src=""/>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:3000" type="button" class="homepg-btn">Çıkış/Ana sayfa</a>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => { 
        simage1.src = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/Brother TN-1040 toner.png";
        simage1.appendChild("Brother TN-1040 toner");
        simage1.appendChild("Price: $100");
    })    
</script>
```

Hello js gurus. I'd like to put some text and a picture together to create a new picture in js. I tried using appendChild method as shown in my attached code but I can't get it to work. When I run the code, all I get is simage1 picture without the text that I want to append. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Putting text nodes, or any elements at all, *inside* a `<img>` element *probably* isn't valid.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to style the text to appear overlayed on the image?  In that case you'd put the text in its own element and use CSS to style the elements in question.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Or do you want to watermark an image?

Comment: `<img>` tags cannot have content, much like `<input>` tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324406/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-and-users-can-also-saved-the-image-with-the-added-te

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) npm library. Look at the Jimp.loadFont method.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a new world of wonders: [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas).

- You can [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) on a `canvas`;
- Write text [`fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) on a `canvas`;
- Export your `canvas` "state" as an image with [`toDataUrl()`](https://%60https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("scene");
const sample = document.getElementById("sample");

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin="anonymous"
image.src = "http://placekitten.com/g/300/150";

image.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 150, 0, 0, 300, 150);

  ctx.font = "50px serif";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.fillText("Hello world", 30, 90);

  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  sample.src = imgData;
});
```

```html
<h1>Canvas</h1>
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>

<h2>Generated image</h2>
<img id="sample" />
```